# Не работает css на двух одинаковых страницах

Tags: node.js

Столкнулся с проблемой, что на двух одинаковых страница не работает один и тот же css. На одной странице css отображатся нормально, а когда подключаю вторую страницу то css перестает работать и в консоле пишет **Refused to apply style from because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.**, хотя путь к css один и тот же.
Вот код

```
var express = require('express'); 
var router = express.Router();


// get /

var Category = require('../models/category');

var Product = require('../models/products');

// it works good and css is working
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    Product.find(function (err, products) {
        if (err) { console.log(err); }


        res.render('all_product', { title: 'All products', products: products });

    });

});


// get products by category
// it works bad and css is not working
router.get('/:category', function (req, res) {
    var categorySlug = req.params.category;

    Category.findOne({ slug: categorySlug }, function (err, c) {
        Product.find({ category: categorySlug }, function (err, products) {
            if (err) { console.log(err); }


            res.render('cat_product', { title: c.title, products: products });

        });
    });



});
```

И вот старница

```
<%- include ('_layouts/header3'); -%>
//<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/catalogstyle.css"> connect css( in header3.ejs). If I delete " ../", it won't work 

    <div id="colRight">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <% products.forEach(function(p){ %>
            <div class="card">
              <div class="face face1">
                <div class="content">
                  <a href="/category/products/<%= p.category %>/<%=p.slug %>"> 
                 <img src="/product_images/<%= p.id %>/<%= p.image %>">
                 </a>
                  <h3><%= p.title %></h3>
                  <h4><%= parseFloat(p.price).toFixed(2) %> грн.</h4>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="face face2">
                <div class="content">
                  <p><%= p.desc %></p>
                  <a href="#">Read More</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <% }); %>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div id="container">
    <%- messages('messages',locals) %>

<%- include ('_layouts/footer3'); -%>
```